# What is this question asking? [Homomorphism, antiderivative mapping]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question is on part 3 of the problem below.

The problem:

Let G be the group of all polynomials with real coefficients under addition. For each f in G, let ∫f denote the antiderivative of f that passes through the point (0, 0). 
1) Show that the mapping f -> ∫f from G to G is a homomorphism.

2) What is the kernel of this mapping?

3) Is this mapping a homomorphism if ∫f denotes the antiderivative of f that passes through (0, 1)?

Attempted Solution:

1) Let f,g∈G, and let φ: G -> G be defined by φ(f) = ∫f. Observe that φ(f+g) = ∫f+g = ∫f + ∫g =  φ(f)+φ(g), so φ is a homomorphism.

2) Kerφ = {f=0}

3) ? This is the question I do not understand. Can someone please explain what it is looking for, and why the coordinates a function passes through can be significant?

Comment: The identity in your group is a polynomial that passes through $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Bettybel Are you saying that Kerφ = {f(0)}?

Comment: No, just answering "why the coordinates a function passes through can be significant?"

Comment: @Bettybel, so can we say that the set would be missing the identity if it does not include any polynomials that pass through (0,0)? I'm not clear on why this is though.

Comment: Review your basic properties of [group homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism). The identity should be mapped to the identity.

Comment: @Bettybel I'm just not understanding the relationship between points on the plane, and elements of the set. I can show that plugging 0 into f, g and taking the antiderivative gives you 1+1 =2, which is not 0, showing that 0 does not map to 0, but the x coordinate 0 is not the identity, a function is.

Comment: Whoever wrote the statement of the problem is identifying polynomials with real coefficients (implicitly assuming them to be of one variable without saying it), with the functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to \mathbb{R} that they define by evaluating them. The functions are also being identified with their graphs. And those graphs are the ones that pass or not pass through points on the plane.

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity: The antiderivative of $f$ passing through $(0, 1)$ can be written$$\varphi(f)(x) = 1 + \int_{0}^{x} f;$$now consider whether or not $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. (Doing so carefully should highlight an important point in your proof of 1. that's glossed over as written.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that:

$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^{n+1}$.

A (general) anti-derivative of $f$ is of the form:

$a_0x + \dfrac{a_1}{2}x^2 + \cdots + \dfrac{a_n}{n+1}x^{n+1} + C$

so if $\phi: \Bbb R[x] \to \Bbb R[x]$ is our homomorphism, we have:

$(\phi(f))(0) = 0$, that is:

$a_0\cdot 0 + \dfrac{a_1}{2}\cdot 0 + \cdots + \dfrac{a_n}{n+1}\cdot 0 + C = 0$.

That is, the constant term of $\phi(f)$ (that is, $C$) must be $0$.

The (additive) identity of our group is not the *number* $0$, but rather the *constant function* $0$, that is $z:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $z(x) = 0$ for *all* $x \in \Bbb R$.

An element of $\text{ker }\phi$ is thus a real polynomial (function) whose anti-derivative (with zero constant term) is the $0$-function.

Ask yourself, can such a polynomial have positive, or zero degree (zero-degree polynomials are non-zero constant polynomials)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems like you are asking for a function that, when you take the antiderivative of it, you get 0 and do not get a +C, but I can't think of anything that would do that. If that is not what you are asking for, then I'm still missing something unfortunately. But to see if I am half following, for #3 in my original post, it seems I could just observe that ϕ(f(0) =  ∫f(0) =  ∫1 = 1x which is not equal to 0, so no function maps to the identity, and therefore prevents ϕ from being a homomorphism. Can you tell me if this is thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Your understanding seems correct. If you just said "an anti-derivative", the mapping would not be well defined. Since you require that it passes through $(0,0)$, you are letting that $C=0$. It is thus a homomorphism. On the other hand, for $C \neq 0$, you don't have a homomorphism for many reasons, one among them the reason you cite.